# DMAR Firmware bug

Tags: bios, firmware

OK, I have seen answers to this problem

> DMAR: [Firmware Bug]: No Firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR, contact BIOS vendor for fixes

But as a complete computer dummy I don't understand the fixes. So can someone explain to me how to fix this with step by step instructions as if speaking to a complete moron please. I've hit desperate times and I really need my laptop to be working. How do I get to the screen I need to type in the fixes as well, cos my computer won't boot up at all.

I would appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks very much in advance.